Why is pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame showing index_col warnings?
Here is its source code.
PySpark has a wapper layer to allow using Pandas API on Spark. Pandas would compute in a single processor unit and it rely on indices. Spark, however, do not use the concept of indices and the data processed distibutely.
I understand that to keep Pandas API compatibility, some methods requires index_col argument. But it will not be used by Spark. If pyspark.pandas is used as just a simpler interface to common, not Pandas-specific methods, we will never define custom idices, it would not speed up queries. If no index is used, why is a warning shown when I call to_spark()? The default integer index will not be saved into a column, I don't know why would I do that.
Is it just a fault in the library, or did I miss something? For example, PySpark Pandas API do build indices for better performance in the background, and there are cases when it helps queries? Maybe the default integer index can help? But how, even if it's distributed Spark would compute the result in the same method.
